# How to calculate inverted ratios? The one with most gets the least kinda thing?

Tags: ratio

Assume that in this question, $A = 20, B = 30, C = 50$.

They find $\$100$ and want to split by ratios such that the one with the least amount at the moment gets the most. $A$ will get the most, $B$ after that, and $C$ the least and this division will be relative to the money they currently have.

If the ratios are not inverted they come out to be $2:3:5$, But how to invert it so $C$ gets the least as he has the most at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely it would just be

\begin{align}&\color{white}=\frac1{20}:\frac1{30}:\frac1{50}\\\\
&=\frac{300}{20}:\frac{300}{30}:\frac{300}{50}\\\\
&=15:10:6\end{align}

Therefore \begin{align}A&\text{ gets } \frac{15}{31}\times 100 \approx \$48.387\cdots\\
B&\text{ gets } \frac{10}{31}\times 100 \approx  \$32.258\cdots\\
C&\text{ gets } \frac{6}{31}\times 100 \approx \$19.354\cdots\end{align}